# Lua: Table inside Object

Tags: lua

I'm using OO abstraction in LUA and I'm having trouble with tables inside objects.

I'm using this approach to implement OO support: [Object Orientation Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial)

If i define a table inside the Class like this:

```
fields = {}
```

It will be shared by all instances of that Class. Something like an static attribute in Java. However, I'd like to get a normal class attribute instead.

That sounds odd to me, since it works correctly for non-table items like this:

```
attribute = 0
```

That is not going to be shared between all instances.

Here is a complete example:

```
local function C1Constructor( self )
    print( "C1: Constructor... " )
    self.fields = {}
end

local function C1SetName( self, name )
    self.name = name
end

local function C1Add( self, name, value )
    print( "C1: (" .. self.name .. ") :: Add: " .. name .. " = " .. value )
    self.fields[ name ] = value
end

local function C1Show( self )
    print( "C1: (" .. self.name .. ") :: Show:" )
    for name, value in pairs( self.fields ) do
        print("    " .. name .. " = " .. value )
    end
end

C1 = {
    name = "",
    constructor = C1Constructor,
    setName     = C1SetName,
    add         = C1Add,
    show        = C1Show,
    fields = {},
}

function C1.new( o )
    o = o or { }
    setmetatable( o, { __index = C1 } )
    o:constructor()
    return o;
end


c1a = C1.new()
c1b = C1.new()
c1a:setName( "Obj A" )
c1b:setName( "Obj B" )
c1a:show()
c1b:show()
c1a:add( "k1", "v1" )
c1b:add( "k2", "v2" )
c1a:show()
c1b:show()
```

I know how to fix it. But I don't know what is happening behind the scenes:

```
local function C1Constructor( self )
    print( "C1: Constructor... " )
    self.fields = {}
end
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks very much,

Comment: Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/lua). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please **do not write** it as _"LUA"_, which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for letting me know. Just my 2c, they should not name both virtualy the same. That is for sure confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables are referenced values. When you store a table in a variable you are storing a reference to the table and not a primitive value (like for a string or a number). As such if you create one table and share it among instances you only have one table. When you create a table per-instance (e.g. in your constructor) then you have one table per-instance and not a shared table.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks very much.
Do you think the per-instance initialization in the constructor is a good approach? If not, can you suggest something better?
Thanks very much.

Comment: If you need per-instance tables for storage then that's a reasonable way to do it. If a large number of instances aren't going to use it and you are worried about memory usage you could consider delayed allocation of the tables but that probably isn't worth the effort.